# Run Multiple SQL statement using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to update the table called Sample from the code below. The first SQL statement works the problem is the SQL statement after if statement. I debugged   and the code is passing the correct values but the table is not updating and I don't have any error

Thanks

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string MBID, ConsentID, ConsentDate, WithdrawDate, ConsentWithdraw;

          MBID = Request.QueryString["mb"].ToString();
          ConsentID = Request.QueryString["ci"].ToString();
          ConsentDate = Request.QueryString["cd"].ToString();
          ConsentWithdraw = Request.QueryString["cw"].ToString();
          WithdrawDate  = Request.QueryString["wd"].ToString();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Molecular"].ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();


            // Update Patient Consent 


            using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"Update ConsentGroup
                                                  set ConsentWithdraw= @ConsentWithdraw, ConsentWithdrawDate= @ConsentWithdrawDate, ConsentDate=@ConsentDate

                                                  WHERE  MBID = @MBID and ConsentID = @ConsentID", con))
            {
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MBID", MBID);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConsentID", ConsentID);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConsentDate", ConsentDate);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConsentWithdraw", ConsentWithdraw);
                sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConsentWithdrawDate", WithdrawDate); 

                Convert.ToInt32(sc.ExecuteScalar());


            }


        // Update Patient Sample  (This part of the code if not working)


            if (ConsentWithdraw == "YES")
            {
                using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"Update Sample
                                                       set ConsentConfirmed='NO'

                                                      WHERE  MBID = @MBID and ConsentNameID = @ConsentID", con))
                {
                    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MBID", MBID);
                    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConsentID", ConsentID);

                    Convert.ToInt32(sc.ExecuteScalar());

                }

            }

            else if (ConsentWithdraw == "NO")
            {
                using (SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand(@"Update Sample
                                                                    set ConsentConfirmed= 'YES'

                                                                  WHERE  MBID = @MBID and ConsentNameID = @ConsentID", con))
                {
                    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MBID", MBID);
                    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConsentID", ConsentID);

                    Convert.ToInt32(sc.ExecuteScalar());
                }
            }


            con.Close();
        }

}
```

JavaScript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

function updateConsent() {
 var MBID = document.getElementById("txtMBIDUpdateConsent").value;
  var ConsentID = document.getElementById("DropDownListUpdateConsent").value;
  var ConsentDate = document.getElementById("txtPatientUpdateConsentDate").value;
  var WithdrawDate = document.getElementById("txtUpdateWithdrawDate").value;
   var ConsentWithdraw = document.getElementById("DropDownListUpdateConsentWithdraw").value;

      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.open("GET", "UpdateConsent.aspx?mb=" + MBID + " &ci= " +
         ConsentID + "&cd=" + ConsentDate + "&wd=" + WithdrawDate+ "&cw="+ ConsentWithdraw, false);
          xmlhttp.send(null);


     ConsentID = document.getElementById("DropDownListUpdateConsent").value = "";
     ConsentDate = document.getElementById("txtPatientUpdateConsentDate").value = "";
      WithdrawDate = document.getElementById("txtUpdateWithdrawDate").value = "";
         ConsentWithdraw= document.getElementById("DropDownListUpdateConsentWithdraw").value="";

         alert("Consent Updated Successfully for MBID    " + MBID);
    }
```

Comment: First, change that ExecuteScalar to ExecuteNonQuery, then catch the return value of ExecuteNonQuery. It should be not zero if any record has been updated. Could you tell us if the return value of ExecuteNonQuery is different from zero? _int records = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();_

Comment: Another problem is AddWithValue with strings that instead are date in the database column. (_WithdrawDate , ConsentDate_) This is well known to cause problems in conversion made by the database engine. Better use Add with a specific parameter type and with a proper DateTime value instead of a string

Comment: Why don't you update everything in one query? It's simple enough to do

Comment: This is probably not the cause of your problem, but [don't use `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Especially not with `DateTime` values that you're passing as strings.

Comment: @ Zohar any help how to run the sql statement in the same query I am updating 2 different table

Comment: Just concatenate the three sql strings together and separate them with a semicolon, but this should not solve your problem because your code is correct. I think you don't have any record in the Sample table that matches your WHERE condition. Thus I have asked you to report the value returned by ExecuteNonQuery on the single separated queries

Comment: @Steve, concatenating may not be a good idea ... rather OP should wrap all the `UPDATE` statement in a procedure. That's the sole purpose of procs

Comment: Sorry, I failed to notice these are different tables. However, the if and else are redundant, since you can simply use the content of `ConsentWithdraw ` as the value to be updated in `ConsentConfirmed`.

Comment: @ zohar You are right I just check int records= sc.ExecuteNonQuery()= 0. That is strange because I just check the database and the value entered exist in the sample table

Comment: @Rahul I am talking about creating a batch command with multiple sql commands.

Comment: @EricMbiada if the return of ExecuteNonQuery is 0 then you don't have that particular record on the targeted database. I suggest to verify the values of the parameters passed to the second and third query

Comment: It is probably a paint issue.  The control doesn't automatically get refresh when new data is added.  The trick  is to set the source (binding) to null and then back to real value.  So if you are using a DGV then datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem I replaced

```
sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConsentID", ConsentID)
```

with

```
sc.Parameters.Add("@ConsentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ConsentID
```

Thanks all for your help